# c# delegate type inference doesn't work as expected when making implicit conversions

Tags: c#, delegates, implicit-conversion

I was playing with delegates and I've bumped into the following problems:

- c# inferences the wrong type for a delegate
- c# converts from method groups to delegates but not all the time

Onwards to the code:

```
public delegate void Act(int i);
public delegate Task ActAsync(int i);

public class Actor
{
    public Act Act { get; private set; }
    public ActAsync ActAsync { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator Actor(Act act)
    {
        return new Actor { Act = act };
    }

    public static implicit operator Actor(ActAsync actAsync)
    {
        return new Actor { ActAsync = actAsync };
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public void ActMethodGroup(int i) { }

    public async Task ActAsyncMethodGroup(int i){}

    public void Test()
    {
        Act act = (i) => { };
        ActAsync actAsync = async (i) => { };
        List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor> {
            (i) => { },         //compiler error: Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'ActAsync'
            async (i) => { },   //compiler error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Actor' because it is not a delegate type
            act,                //works fine because act is of type 'Act'
            actAsync,           //works fine because actAsync is of type 'ActAsync'
            ActMethodGroup,     //compiler error: Cannot convert from 'method group' to Actor
            ActAsyncMethodGroup //compiler error: Cannot convert from 'method group' to Actor
        };

        List<Act> actList = new List<Act>
        {
            act,                //works fine because act is of type 'Act'
            ActMethodGroup      //works fine, but why?
        };

        List<ActAsync> actAsyncList = new List<ActAsync>
        {
            actAsync,           //works fine because actAsync is of type 'ActAsync'
            ActAsyncMethodGroup //works fine, but why?
        };
    }
}
```

Questions:

- why does the `(i) => { }` lambda get matched as ActAsync instead of Act when passed in the `new List<Actor>` list initializer
- why does type inference fail for `async (i) => { }` when passed in the `new List<Actor>` list initializer
- why does `ActMethodGroup` get converted into the proper type in the `new List<Act>` initializer but not in the `new List<Actor>` initializer

Comment: Either you're in a context where, perhaps because of other factors, there is only one possible delegate type available, such as `public void Test(Func<int> f)`, or you're in a context where the delegate already have a type. If you're in the third context, you have multiple options, and a lambda/anonymous method without a currently known delegate type *type*, then the compiler simply raises his (or her) hands and gives up. Simply put, the compiler sees two possible delegate types, and a lambda for which it has to come up with a delegate type wrapper, and doesn't know which to use.

Comment: Sometimes the "wrong" type wins in an ambiguous setting, sometimes you get an error that it is ambiguous. The problem is the same though, not enough information.

Comment: `async (i) => { }` is not a method returning a task and therefore it is again possible to use this for both overloads.

Comment: `(Actor)((i) => { })`.

Comment: The reason why the method groups cannot be converted directly to Actor is again because of too little information. Before one of the operators can be used, the compiler has to know either which delegate to use (it doesn't, you've told it to attempt a direct conversion to Actor) or there would already be a typed delegate around the method, which there isn't. Lack of information. In the two other lists, it knows which delegate to attempt to convert the method group to and thus manages it.

Comment: You should really be asking one question per question.  Asking a whole bunch of different questions in a single question makes your question too broad.

Comment: So the answer boils down to `there is no type inference for delegates` which I would have noticed had I tried to assign a delegate to an implicitly typed variable.

Comment: anonymous\lambda method just doesn't have a type by itself. It's type is determined by the context where it used. If you add your `(i) => { }` to `List<Act>` - its type will be correctly inferred to be `Act`.

Comment: You're initializing a `List<Actor>`. None of the items you're initializing it with is an `Actor`. Perhaps you meant `List<Act> acts = new List<Act>`?